# Create a box-and-whisker plot for (category, value) categorical data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, statistics

In MS Excel (and LO Calc), you can easily create a box-and-whisker plot if your data is arranged like so:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 78 | 634 |
| 4 | 56 | 449 |
| 9 | 34 | 315 |
| 16 | 21 | 809 |

and you'll get three boxes, one for each category, regarding 4 samples in my example.

But what if my data is arranged like so?

| category | value |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1 |
| bar | 78 |
| baz | 634 |
| foo | 4 |
| foo | 9 |

etc. etc.? When I do this naively, MS simply draws two boxes, one for each column. Transposing the data doesn't help either.

Is there anything I can do to make Excel properly respect my categorization - other than creating a PivotTable where the data is arranged as in the first example?

Comment: When you say transposing doesn't help, do you also mean unpivoting (via Power Query) doesn't help? I would think that unpivotong would set up the data just like your first table example.

Comment: @bugdrown: I just meant a plain transposition (e.g. copy and pasting with the transpose option). I haven't actually ever used Power Queries in Excel TBH.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data into a form appropriate for a Box and Whisker plot.
And how to do it depends on the version of Excel you use.
If you have the FILTER function, the easiest way is to use this function:

```
=FILTER(data, groups="foo")
```

If you have an older version of Excel, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(groups="foo", data),ROW(A1)),NA())
```

or even like this:

```
=IF(groups="foo", data, NA())
```

#N/A values do not interfere with the creation of this type of chart.
[image: Data for a Box and Whisker plot]

Comment: So, `FILTER()` produces a table, rather than a cell value?

Comment: As a rule, yes.

Comment: @einpoklum, it depends on how fine your filter is. The filter formula  could return just one value, in essence a table of one cell.